# Rigid-body bars in a double pendulum setup

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, classical-mechanics

[image]

I've heard double pendulums are notoriously chaotic in their motion and that no closed-form solution to their ODEs of motion exist.

Setting, by the theorem of kinetic energy $$\dot T= \Pi$$ I end up with:

$$4l_1\dot \theta_1 \ddot \theta_1(\frac {1}{3}m_1+m_2)+\frac{4}{3}l_2^2\dot\theta_2 \ddot \theta_2 m_2+2m_2l_1l_2 \{[\ddot \theta_1 \dot \theta_2+\ddot \theta_2 \dot \theta_1]sin(\theta_1-\theta_2)+\dot \theta_1 \dot \theta_2[\dot \theta_1 - \dot \theta_2]cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)\}=g[(\frac{m_1}{2}+m_2)l_1cos(\theta_1)\dot \theta_1-\frac{m_2l_2}{2}sin(\theta_2)\dot \theta_2]$$
Which is gnarly to say the least. I have only taken an introductory Analytical Mechanics course but I have a feeling this is one of those "no-closed-form-exists" ODEs.

To summarise how I obtained the above formula,
$$T=\frac{1}{2}(m_1v_G^2+I_G \dot \theta_1^2+m_2v_H^2+I_H\dot \theta_2^2)$$
And $$\Pi=\frac{dW}{dt}=-m_1g \dot Y_G-m_2g \dot Y_H=g[(\frac{m_1}{2}+m_2)l_1cos(\theta_1)\dot \theta_1-\frac{m_2l_2}{2}sin(\theta_2)\dot \theta_2]$$

(This is assumed to be a 2D analysis of rigid bodies with perfect restraints).

Is there a way to further simplify the equation of motion for this general case with unspecified parameters?

Comment: Shouldn't you end up with a system of two ODEs (configuration mfld is two dimensional with $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$). Also, I don't expect velocity terms multiplying the acceleration. I think this class of systems takes the form $M(q) q'' + C(q, q') q' + G(q) = 0.$

Comment: I admit I kind of just chucked my current problem solving knowledge at this configuration without much setup. We only ever studied systems with 1 degree of freedom: this always implies a closed-form virtual work equation (there's always an equilibrium value for the free coordinate, provided a solution exists) and the cancelling-out of all velocity terms in Tdot = P. I figured since the maths holds I could do the same for 2 degrees of freedom but, there being 2 free coordinates, some terms just don't cancel out.

Comment: The standard way for general systems is to invoke the Euler-Lagrange equations (derivable from principle of least action). Might be worth comparing your approach with this (it does differ slightly in $\dot T$). In this case it would result in a system of two nonlinear ODEs of the form I described earlier. Regardless, yes, there is no known closed-form solution to that system.

Comment: Thank you for your insight! I haven't studied calculus of variations nor its applications in physics, but I'm familiar enough with the big idea behind it. I will try to compare that approach with mine.